# When Change any fragment data state remain as is no reload data

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do i swapping one fragment to another fragment so enter data as remain means i have one fragment in that one search functionality.
in that user can entered different keyword by search but it navigate from one to other fragment that data is erased i want that entered data remain as it is.
is it possible if yes than how ?

Comment: You have a searchview in that you have entered some text based on that you have filtered some data, but when you go to another fragment and returned to previous fragment you are losing the the filtered data is this your question?

Comment: yes sir you are right

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: right now no do that but fragment life cycle follow that and previously i used fragment that time i face that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not very clear...

Passing arguments from a fragment to another can be done with a `Bundle`.

I give you an example.
Store the data your user type in a String and put it in a Bundle like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("NAME OF YOUR DATA", "VALUE OF YOUR DATA");
new YourFragmentClass().setArguments(bundle);
```

Then on your second fragment, get your data this way:

```
Bundle data = getArguments();
data.getString("NAME OF YOUR DATA","DEFAULT VALUE IF THIS DOESNT EXIST")
```

You can then keep your data from a fragment to another.

If it doesnt fit to your needs, have a look on the `SharedPreferences`

Comment: thanks sir i got your answer but i also implement in also any image editing
i.e i am doing image edit and swipe from one to another and back again so remain whatever image edit as it is

Comment: in this case, use hide() and show() methods instead of replace or add. It will keep your view as it is> good luck :)

Comment: let me be more accurate: what you can do is create your fragments before setting the data. Add the one you want to show first as the last. Then you the method hide() and show() or your fragment to navigate without destroying the view, and this way keeping the view as it is ( You have to add the following code around your oncreateview content: if (mainview == null) {... content ... }else {return mainview;}

Comment: thanks sir i got it now i implement that